# How to create members?

Tags: users

I would like to develop a members plugin so it can be used for mailing lists, volunteers etc....
I read [Customizing WP tables or adding new ones?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/230191/customizing-wp-tables-or-adding-new-ones) & [Objective Best Practices for Plugin Development?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/715/objective-best-practices-for-plugin-development)

What I wish to know/ understand is:
Should I use WordPress' existing `users` table with all the enhanced functionality that comes with it?
OR
Should I create a new table cloning WordPress' `users` table so not to run into issues upon WordPress updates, my plugin updates etc....
& if so, can I use the built in WordPress users core functions to manipulate the new table?

Comment: Yes you should use the existing user table. Why mess with a good thing :) You can add custom stuff for users in de usermeta table.

Comment: You can use the existing users table and add a new role https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities